# Limit usage for Plot3D

Tags: plotting, regions

Suppose I need to plot a function $z = x^2 - y^2$ using a 3 dimensional surface plot (`Plot3D` feature). Assume the $x$ limit for this plot is `[x_min, x_max]` and `y` limit is `[y_min, y_max]`. In my case, x_max is a function of co-ordinate y. How do I incorporate this in the `Plot3D` command ?

Eg. `Plot3D[x^2-y^2, {xlim, x_min, x_max(y)}, {ylim, y_min, y_max}]` does not work.

Comment: Maybe try with [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be dependency in the limits, the trick is to order the independent variables first:

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, y^3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, 
      {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x < y^3 + 4 && 0 < y < 2]]
```

Here, the upper limit of the region is explicit in `0 < x < y^3 + 4`.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand how we are using the upper limit of x here as a function of y. Say x_max = y^3 + 4. How do we incorporate that using your method.

Comment: Equivalently, you can give a region as a plotting domain: `Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[0 < x < y^3 + 4 && 0 < y < 2, {x, y}]]`